# How to use custom png image marker with plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to utilize customer markers in both scatter and line charts. How can I make custom marker out of a PNG file?

Comment: I suggest this be marked as a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324270/matplotlib-custom-marker-symbol

Comment: Instead of png images one can check if there exist a fontset that contains an appropriate symbol, that could be used as marker. Either one could use standard utf8 symbols as in [Matplotlib custom marker/symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324270/matplotlib-custom-marker-symbol), or if a specific font is needed, an example would be in [How to use Font Awesome symbol as marker in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52902086/how-to-use-font-awesome-symbol-as-marker-in-matplotlib).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I don't believe matplotlib can customize markers like that.  See [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/scatter_piecharts.html) for the level of customization, which falls way short of what you need.

As an alternative, I've coded up this kludge which uses `matplotlib.image` to place images at the line point locations.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import image

# constant
dpi = 72
path = 'smile.png'
# read in our png file
im = image.imread(path)
image_size = im.shape[1], im.shape[0]

fig = plt.figure(dpi=dpi)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# plot our line with transparent markers, and markersize the size of our image
line, = ax.plot((1,2,3,4),(1,2,3,4),"bo",mfc="None",mec="None",markersize=image_size[0] * (dpi/ 96))
# we need to make the frame transparent so the image can be seen
# only in trunk can you put the image on top of the plot, see this link:
# http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg14534.html
ax.patch.set_alpha(0)
ax.set_xlim((0,5))
ax.set_ylim((0,5))

# translate point positions to pixel positions
# figimage needs pixels not points
line._transform_path()
path, affine = line._transformed_path.get_transformed_points_and_affine()
path = affine.transform_path(path)
for pixelPoint in path.vertices:
    # place image at point, centering it
    fig.figimage(im,pixelPoint[0]-image_size[0]/2,pixelPoint[1]-image_size[1]/2,origin="upper")

plt.show()
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_frame'

Comment: See answer by t gillespie for handling get_frame error

Answer (score 9):

Following on from Mark's answer. I just thought I would add to this a bit because I tried to run this and it does what I want with the exception of actually displaying the icons on the graph. Maybe something has changed with matplotlib. It *has* been 4 years.

The line of code that reads:

```
ax.get_frame().set_alpha(0)
```

does not seem to work, however

```
ax.patch.set_alpha(0)
```

does work.

Answer (score 8):

The other answer may lead to problems when resizing the figure. Here is a different approach, positionning the images inside annotation boxes, which are anchored in data coordinates.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

path = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/Tango-example_icons.png"
image = plt.imread(path)[116:116+30, 236:236+30]

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

def plot_images(x, y, image, ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()

    for xi, yi in zip(x,y):
        im = OffsetImage(image, zoom=72/ax.figure.dpi)
        im.image.axes = ax

        ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (xi,yi), frameon=False, pad=0.0,)

        ax.add_artist(ab)

plot_images(x, y, image, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]