# Each marker with a different color

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In a similar vein to: [Matplotlib scatterplot; colour as a function of a third variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202605/matplotlib-scatterplot-colour-as-a-function-of-a-third-variable), can one specify the color of each marker separately in a **regular** `ax.plot() (i.e. without using a scatterplot).

If I try:

```
cmap  = sns.color_palette("Greys",5)
color = np.array(cmap)[[0,4],:]

ax.plot(X, Y, color=color, markersize=12, marker='o', linewidth=0)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "[[ 0.91252596  0.91252596  0.91252596]
```

Comment: Maybe you could plot the lines first using `plot` and then add the markers afterwards with `scatter`?

Comment: AFAIK, that is not possible. What is the reason you do not want to use `scatter()`? The example you provide would work just fine using that instead of  `plot()`

Comment: Thanks @DizietAsahi I am hoping to use my own type of marker. Can we do that with `scatter` ?

Answer (score 4):

Its not possible to plot different markets with `plot()`. That is the whole point of `scatter` - you get more options. To make custom markers see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324270/matplotlib-custom-marker-symbol).