# How do you style a scatter plot like this?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have used the following code to make a scatter plot look like this:

plt.scatter(x, y, marker='|')

[image]

Now however I want it to look something like this:

[image]

How do I do this? Please do ignore the background and the orange line thingy, that's a different graph altogether. Thanks!

Comment: You can run the scatter command twice, with two different markers that will be shown on the same image. Just make sure to explicitly set the color for both the same.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could scatter twice with the same color. Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324270/matplotlib-custom-marker-symbol).

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

xs = np.random.randn(100)
ys = np.random.randn(100)

plt.scatter(xs, ys, color="blue")
plt.scatter(xs, ys, s = 200, marker='|', color='blue')
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that what you want to achieve is (or at least looks similar to) a "dot plus error bar" marker style. If you are not plotting error bars, I would strongly discourage that style. If you want to plot errorbars, I would suggest

```
plt.errorbar(xs, ys, dys, marker='.', ls='')
```

given that `dys` are the errors (uncertainties) in the y dimension.