# Can you add a number to a plotted line in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib.pyplot to plot different lines. I can add a legend with a label to tell which line is which by color.  Unfortunately I am color blind.  Is it possible to write a number embedded in each line instead?  The numbers could look like this.

[image]

These could then identify each line.

Comment: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324270/matplotlib-custom-marker-symbol) for custom markers. You could also try using a colormap that is suited for colorblindness if this is an option.

Comment: @warped can you add the marker to the legend too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice little package `matplotlib-label-lines` that accomplishes this (the code is [here](https://github.com/cphyc/matplotlib-label-lines) on github).

After installing this package, your code could look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import labellines

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x, x**2, linewidth=2, label="line example")
labellines.labelLines(ax.get_lines())

plt.show()
```

Which would give you something like this.

You could also you different line style, instead of color, in your legend. 
[image]

Comment: Can you then do the same thing in the legend?

Comment: Yes, just add the command `ax.legend()` and then the lines will be labeled in the plot and on the legend.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324270/matplotlib-custom-marker-symbol).

You can use latex math symbols in matplotlib.
Since $1$ counts as latex math symbol, you can use it as marker.

Example with 0,1,2:

```
x, y, = np.arange(10), np.arange(10)

for a in range(3):

    plt.plot(x, a*y, alpha=0.5, marker='${}$'.format(a), markersize=10, label=a)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### edit

Plotting number only once on the curve

```
x, y, = np.arange(10), np.arange(10)

colors = ['teal', 'darkslateblue', 'orange']

for a in range(3):

    plt.plot(x, a*y, c=colors[a])
    plt.plot(x[a+3], a*y[a+3], alpha=0.5, marker='${}$'.format(a), markersize=10, label=a, c=colors[a])

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have the label only once on each line?

Comment: Thank you very much.