# How to change default markers in scatterplot Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot, markers

I'm trying to add weather markers instead of basic circles in a scatterplot. More specifically, I'd like to show physical and mental changes depending on weather conditions. For this purpose, I'd like to use some weather icons (.svg files) instead of differently colored circles. However, I obtain the following error:

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'Path'`

Here's my code:

```
clear_marker = parse_path("""M 350.04,161.95
           C 350.04,161.95 391.76,120.24 391.76,120.24M 120.24,391.76
           C 120.24,391.76 161.96,350.04 161.96,350.04M 389.00,256.00
           C 389.00,256.00 448.00,256.00 448.00,256.00M 64.00,256.00
           C 64.00,256.00 123.00,256.00 123.00,256.00M 350.04,350.04
           C 350.04,350.04 391.76,391.76 391.76,391.76M 120.24,120.24
           C 120.24,120.24 161.96,161.95 161.96,161.95M 256.00,389.00
           C 256.00,389.00 256.00,447.99 256.00,447.99M 256.00,64.00
           C 256.00,64.00 256.00,123.00 256.00,123.00M 157.56,216.68M 150.90,242.12
           C 150.31,246.60 150.00,251.26 150.00,256.00
             150.00,256.01 150.00,256.02 150.00,256.02
             150.00,314.57 197.46,362.02 256.00,362.02
             314.54,362.02 362.00,314.57 362.00,256.02
             362.00,197.48 314.54,150.02 256.00,150.02
             220.35,150.02 188.80,167.63 169.59,194.62M 276.00,170.00
           C 217.46,170.00 170.01,217.46 170.01,276.00
             170.01,300.17 178.09,322.45 191.71,340.28
             209.54,353.90 231.82,361.99 255.99,361.99
             314.53,361.99 361.99,314.53 361.99,255.99
             361.99,231.83 353.90,209.55 340.29,191.72
             322.52,178.10 300.28,170.00 276.16,170.00
             276.11,170.00 276.05,170.00 276.00,170.00
             276.00,170.00 276.00,170.00 276.00,170.00 Z""")
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', marker = clear_marker)
```

*(I only tried on the first marker to see if it worked)*

THANKS.

Comment: See [Matplotlib custom marker/symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58552620/12046409)

Comment: Which matplotlib version are you using? I tried this with version 3.4.3, leaving out the `'o'` and adding `ls=''`. So, `plt.plot(x, y, ls='', marker=clear_marker)`, producing star-shaped markers. Note that it might help to subtract the mean to nicely center the marker: `clear_marker.vertices -= clear_marker.vertices.mean(axis=0)`

Comment: I'm using matplotlib 3.4.3. I did the same but still "unhashable type: Path". Also I'm using svg.path 4.1 (function parse_path).

Comment: The linked post uses `!pip install svgpath2mpl matplotlib`  and `from svgpath2mpl import parse_path`.  version `1.0.0`

Comment: `svg.path` doesn't seem to create matplotlib paths. You need `svgpath2mpl `