# Marker filling options Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I need more marker-filling options. I came up with this trick to make a more interesting marker without using colours.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a = np.random.random(5)
b = np.random.random(5)
[ax.scatter(a, b, s=eses, edgecolor='k', lw=.5, color='None', label = 'This is not what I want') for eses in [200, 100, 30, 1]]
ax.set_title('Marker options')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

I have two questions:

1. how to fix the legend so that the same concentric rings show up as one symbol in the legend instead of four symbols of different sizes.
2. how to get a dashed circle for a marker (circle with parallel - diagonal lines inside of it), or a circle filled with dots.

---

**EDIT**: Thanks to the users who commented. I've seen both websites suggested before posting my question; however, I am not looking for custom marker shapes.
I am looking for custom fillings for a simple circle marker.

Comment: You might want to look into creating custom markers. This site seems to show some methods: https://petercbsmith.github.io/marker-tutorial.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib custom marker/symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324270/matplotlib-custom-marker-symbol)

Comment: Matplotlib's [marker reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html) has a long list of possibilities. To combine multiple markers into one legend entry, there is [legend_handler.HandlerTuple](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/legend_guide.html).

Comment: Please don't abuse list comprehensions like that.