# Putting custom objects as datapoints in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to make scatter plots. I want the markers in my scatter plot to be custom objects. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Possibly [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318288/how-to-use-custom-marker-with-plot)?

Comment: If you want PNG images as the markers, see the duplicate question noted by @SukritKalra. If you want something simple like custom circles or squares, that may be possible. You should quantify what you are looking for.

Comment: Say, the markers in my plot represent "XYZ" at different locations. When I click on the marker I should be able to see other details(like name,id etc.) of the XYZ object.How do I associate the markers to XYZ object?

Comment: If you want to click on the markers and then have some action happen, you might want to look at this demo: http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html

Comment: also, https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor/