# Is it possible to control matplotlib marker orientation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

If I have a triangular marker, is it possible to control its orientation? I have a series of facets, with their corresponding vertices, and I would like to plot a basemap of them. I know it is straightforward script when using Mayavi and tvtk.PolyData. But since I'm dealing with maps and not 3D objects, things got a bit complicated.

ps: for maps I'm using basemap tool.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can create [custom polygons](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html) using the keyword argument `marker` and passing it a tuple of 3 numbers `(number of sides, style, rotation)`.

To create a triangle you would use `(3, 0, rotation)`, an example is shown below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3]
for i in x:
    plt.plot(i, i, marker=(3, 0, i*90), markersize=20, linestyle='None')

plt.xlim([0,4])
plt.ylim([0,4])

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Could the triangles not be equilateral? And could I pass a Nx3-shape tuple, instead iterating over each facet?

Comment: The triangles have to be equilateral with this method (it creates a regular polygon so if you passed it 4 it would create a square). I don't think matplotlib is able to create more advanced symbols than that by itself. If you could generate the symbols you want yourself as images you could possibly try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318288/how-to-use-custom-marker-with-plot)

Comment: How could I make the 3rd element i.e rotation - a dataframe series. 

Im plotting in terms of , x=df1['A'], y=df1['Speed'] z=df1['Direction']

Comment: @SLE off the top of my head, it's be exactly the same really. You'd have to iterate row-wise over the dataframe and do `plt.plot(df['A'], df['Speed'], marker = (...some calculation that you want that uses df['Direction']...))`. Not very efficient (iterating and plotting N single points like that) though. If you have M directions that are shared with other rows (N, S, E, W as an example) then you could index the df by direction and then plot those indexed parts, then you'd just have M different `plt.plot` calls for the M different directions.

Answer (score 16):

I just wanted to add a method to rotate other ***non-regular polygon marker styles***. Below I have rotated the "thin diamond" and "plus" and "vline" by modifying the transform attribute of the marker style class.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for m in ['d', '+', '|']:

    for i in range(5):
        a1, a2  = np.random.random(2)
        angle = np.random.choice([180, 45, 90, 35])

        # make a markerstyle class instance and modify its transform prop
        t = mpl.markers.MarkerStyle(marker=m)
        t._transform = t.get_transform().rotate_deg(angle)
        plt.scatter((a1), (a2), marker=t, s=100)
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed that `plt.plot` does not accept MarkerStyle objects, it throws an error: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'MarkerStyle'`. `plt.scatter`works fine though.

Answer (score 6):

## solution with custom `matplotlib.path.Path` (irregular triangle)

If you look for a marker symbol, where you can clearly decline the orientation from [0, 2pi), you can construct a [marker from a path](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html).
As paths are automatically scaled by the plotting routine (such that the most outer point touches the box -1 <= x, y <= 1), you need additional point size scaling.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def gen_arrow_head_marker(rot):
    """generate a marker to plot with matplotlib scatter, plot, ...

    https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers

    rot=0: positive x direction
    Parameters
    ----------
    rot : float
        rotation in degree
        0 is positive x direction

    Returns
    -------
    arrow_head_marker : Path
        use this path for marker argument of plt.scatter
    scale : float
        multiply a argument of plt.scatter with this factor got get markers
        with the same size independent of their rotation.
        Paths are autoscaled to a box of size -1 <= x, y <= 1 by plt.scatter
    """
    arr = np.array([[.1, .3], [.1, -.3], [1, 0], [.1, .3]])  # arrow shape
    angle = rot / 180 * np.pi
    rot_mat = np.array([
        [np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)],
        [-np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle)]
        ])
    arr = np.matmul(arr, rot_mat)  # rotates the arrow

    # scale
    x0 = np.amin(arr[:, 0])
    x1 = np.amax(arr[:, 0])
    y0 = np.amin(arr[:, 1])
    y1 = np.amax(arr[:, 1])
    scale = np.amax(np.abs([x0, x1, y0, y1]))
    codes = [mpl.path.Path.MOVETO, mpl.path.Path.LINETO,mpl.path.Path.LINETO, mpl.path.Path.CLOSEPOLY]
    arrow_head_marker = mpl.path.Path(arr, codes)
    return arrow_head_marker, scale

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for rot in [0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 90, 110, 180, 210, 315, 360]:

    marker, scale = gen_arrow_head_marker(rot)
    markersize = 25
    ax.scatter(rot, 0, marker=marker, s=(markersize*scale)**2)

ax.set_xlabel('Rotation in degree')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [matplotlib.markers](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html) module:

> `(numsides, 0, angle)` -
> A regular polygon with `numsides` sides, rotated by `angle`.
> `(numsides, 1, angle)` -
> A star-like symbol with `numsides` sides, rotated by `angle`.
> `(numsides, 2, angle)` -
> An asterisk with `numsides` sides, rotated by `angle`.

So for example, you can use an arbitrary polygon with a specified angle:

```
marker = (3, 0, 45)  # triangle rotated by 45 degrees.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a better and more comprehensive answer [as for Matplotlib 3.3.3](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/markers_api.html) :

There is an option "verts" for specifiyng the marker, which has the form of a list of (x,y) tuples, these being the vertices of your path. This allows you to draw a marker of virtually any shape, filled or not, open or closed etc. As far as I've tested, the other marker options (see below) are still applicable.

For example

```
   plt.plot(x,y,
       marker=[(0,-24),(-10,-20),(10,-16),(-10,12),(10,8),(0,-4),(0,0)],
       markersize=42, color='w', linestyle='None',
       markeredgecolor='k', markeredgewidth= 2.)
```

will create a marker with the shape of a spring. The size is automatically mapped to a unit square, and your point (0,0) will be placed at x,y.
From here, making a function to rotate a given angle the whole list of coordinates should be a trivial task.

[image: custom, spring-shaped, marker]