# Python- Plotting phase space trajectories (quiver function)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

In the code below, I have found the solution to a system of differential equations. I have plotted the phase space trajectory within this code and it works fine. However, I was looking to repeat the plot but with arrows to help me clearly show what the plot means. 
I have seen that a similar question has been asked:
[Drawing phase space trajectories with arrows in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607742/drawing-phase-space-trajectories-with-arrows-in-matplotlib)
and hence in the code below I have tried to replicate it for my situation. (I would post this question on that thread, but it won't allow me to)

When i run the code, the images I get are as follows:

[image: Phase space trajectories]

Obviously I have misunderstood the quiver function at some point (as the plots should look the same (just the second one should have arrows) this is clearly not the case, also I have seen that altering the number of points in my linspace changes the second plot drastically).

My code is as follows:

```
# Import the required modules
import numpy as np
from run_kut4 import *
from printSoln import *
import pylab

def G2(x,y):
    G2=np.zeros(2)
    G2[0]=y[1]
    G2[1]=-np.sin(y[0])+0.02*np.cos(y[0])*np.sin(x)
    return G2
x2=0.0
xstop2=40.0
y2=np.array([0.0,0.0]) 
h2=0.005#step size
#freq=1

X2,Y2=integrate(G2,x2,y2,xstop2,h2)

pylab.plot(Y2[:,0],Y2[:,1])
pylab.xlabel('θ')
pylab.ylabel('dθ/dx')
pylab.title('Phase space trajectory (resonant case)')
pylab.show()

y1=np.linspace(-0.4,0.4,100)
y2=np.linspace(-0.4,0.4,100)
U,V=np.meshgrid(y1,y2)

pylab.quiver(U,V,Y2[:,0],Y2[:,1])
pylab.xlabel('θ')
pylab.ylabel('dθ/dx')
pylab.title('Phase space trajectory (resonant case)')
pylab.show()
```

I was just wondering if anyone could see where I have gone wrong, any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

I have attempted to switch U and V as the syntax suggested, and gotten this:
[image: Phase space traj 2]

Runge Kutta code used:

```
  ## module run_kut4
  ''' X,Y = integrate(F,x,y,xStop,h).
  4th-order Runge-Kutta method for solving the
  initial value problem {y}' = {F(x,{y})}, where
  {y} = {y[0],y[1],...y[n-1]}.
  x,y   = initial conditions
  xStop = terminal value of x
  h     = increment of x used in integration
  F     = user-supplied function that returns the
  array F(x,y) = {y'[0],y'[1],...,y'[n-1]}.
  '''
import numpy as np
def integrate(F,x,y,xStop,h):

def run_kut4(F,x,y,h):
    K0 = h*F(x,y)
    K1 = h*F(x + h/2.0, y + K0/2.0)
    K2 = h*F(x + h/2.0, y + K1/2.0)
    K3 = h*F(x + h, y + K2)
    return (K0 + 2.0*K1 + 2.0*K2 + K3)/6.0    

X = []
Y = []
X.append(x)
Y.append(y)
while x < xStop:
    h = min(h,xStop - x)
    y = y + run_kut4(F,x,y,h)
    x = x + h
    X.append(x)
    Y.append(y)
return np.array(X),np.array(Y)
```

Comment: The quiver function is used as:
pylab.quiver(X, Y, U, V)
So maybe replace your line with:
pylab.quiver(Y2[:,0],Y2[:,1], U, V)

Comment: I tried that before, It just makes a weird version of the plot (still no arrows)... I have edited the image into the original post

Comment: Please let me know if my answer works for you.

Comment: Yes, that is very helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code given in ["Drawing phase space trajectories in Matplotlib with arrows"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607742/drawing-phase-space-trajectories-with-arrows-in-matplotlib) works for your case too if you reduce the step size `h=0.1`. We can generate the following figure.
[image: Arrows]

```
# Import the required modules
import numpy as np
from run_kut4 import *
import pylab

def G2(x,y):
    G2=np.zeros(2)
    G2[0]=y[1]
    G2[1]=-np.sin(y[0])+0.02*np.cos(y[0])*np.sin(x)
    return G2
x2=0.0
xstop2=40.0
y2=np.array([0.0,0.0])
h2=0.1#step size
#freq=1

X2,Y2=integrate(G2,x2,y2,xstop2,h2)

#pylab.plot(Y2[:,0],Y2[:,1])
pylab.xlabel('θ')
pylab.ylabel('dθ/dx')
pylab.title('Phase space trajectory (resonant case)')
pylab.show()

pylab.quiver(Y2[:-1,0], Y2[:-1,1], Y2[1:,0]-Y2[:-1,0], Y2[1:,1]-Y2[:-1, 1])
pylab.xlabel('θ')
pylab.ylabel('dθ/dx')
pylab.title('Phase space trajectory (resonant case)')
pylab.show()
```

If you don't like the previous plot you can skip the `quiver` plot altogether and simply change the plot command to `pylab.plot(Y2[:,0],Y2[:,1],'->')`. This gives a plot like
[image: Arrows2]

Comment: where can I get run_kut4 package? Is it ur customised one?

Comment: It is a custom one, I have edited the question to include it if you want to use it

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to overlay the quiver on your plot, use `y1` and `y2` in the `X` and `Y` positions:

```
plt.quiver(y1, y2, U, V, alpha=.3)
```

[image: quiver]

Note: The post you linked to actually has arrows tracking the curves themselves, but you're using a `meshgrid` over `linspace` for `U` and `V` here, so I'm assuming you just want this grid of arrows.

Comment: The arrows are meant to point in the direction of the lines, so it is essentially a map and you can follow the trajectory (of in this case, a pendulum)