# Rotate existing matplotlib markers?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm aware of this answer, [Is it possible to control matplotlib marker orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345565/is-it-possible-to-control-matplotlib-marker-orientation?noredirect=1&lq=1), and the marker documentation, but is it possible to take an existing matplotlib marker symbol (nonregular polygon) and rotate it?

Specifically, I would like to rotate the thin diamond symbol ("d") 90 degrees, such that its long axis is horizontal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The marker `"d"` is a skewed version of a diamond, `"D"`. You may create such diamond marker and skew it in the other direction.

For arbitrary angles, you may rotate the marker instead.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.markers import MarkerStyle

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.scatter([1,2,3],[1,2,3], s=225, marker="d")

m = MarkerStyle("D")
m._transform.scale(1.0, 0.6)

plt.scatter([1,2,3],[2,3,4], s=225, marker=m, color="crimson")

m = MarkerStyle("d")
m._transform.rotate_deg(60)

plt.scatter([1,2,3],[3,4,5], s=225, marker=m, color="limegreen")

plt.margins(0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for... except that I want to use errorbar instead of scatter.  Remarkably, it fails!  The final error is `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'MarkerStyle'`.  Anybody know a fix?

Comment: (I created a separate question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64106682/rotate-matplotlib-markers-with-errorbar-plot and opened https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18600 to try and find a fix.)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this if you make a markerstyle class for a diamond and then modify its transform property yourself with a rotation, for whatever reason matplotlib didn't expose these class attributes for certain markers.  I've included an example below.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make a markerstyle class and modify the transform property by 90 degrees
t = mpl.markers.MarkerStyle(marker='d')
t._transform = t.get_transform().rotate_deg(90)
plt.scatter((0,1), (0,1), marker=t, s=100)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The rotation angel is given in 360-degree units:

```
x = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
for i in x:

    plt.plot(i, i, marker=(2, 0, -i), c='k',markersize=30, linestyle='None')
plt.margins(0.15); plt.grid();plt.show()
```

[image]