# Rotate matplotlib markers with errorbar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I was following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49662571/) for rotating pre-existing matplotlib markers.

However, the solution there doesn't work with errorbar plots.  Here's a simple `example.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.markers import MarkerStyle

# I want to use this marker in an errorbar plot
m = MarkerStyle("D")
m._transform.scale(1.0, 0.6)

# I can use it in a scatter plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.scatter([1,2,3],[1,2,3], s=225, marker="d")
plt.scatter([1,2,3],[2,3,4], s=225, marker=m, color="crimson")
plt.show()
# which produces a figure similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49662571/

# But when I use it in errorbar
fix, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.errorbar([1,2,3],[3,4,5], yerr=[0.5,0.5,0.5], marker=m, color='green')
plt.show()

# I get
#>Traceback (most recent call last):
#>  File "./example.py", line 19, in <module>
#>    plt.errorbar([1,2,3],[3,4,5], yerr=[0.5,0.5,0.5], marker=m, color='green')
#>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2524, in errorbar
#>    return gca().errorbar(
#>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1565, in inner
#>    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
#>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3265, in errorbar
#>    data_line = mlines.Line2D(x, y, **plot_line_style)
#>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 378, in __init__
#>    self._marker = MarkerStyle(marker, fillstyle)
#>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/markers.py", line 225, in __init__
#>    self.set_marker(marker)
#>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/markers.py", line 289, in set_marker
#>    Path(marker)
#>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/path.py", line 127, in __init__
#>    vertices = _to_unmasked_float_array(vertices)
#>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 1317, in _to_unmasked_float_array
#>    return np.asarray(x, float)
#>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 83, in asarray
#>    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
#>TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'MarkerStyle'
```

**Q:  How can I use a rotated pre-existing matplotlib marker (or, maybe, any MarkerStyle marker) in an errorbar plot?**  (Really I want a 90˚ rotation of `thin_diamond`.)

Comment: (I have `matplotlib.__version__=='3.2.2'`)

Comment: I opened https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be two bugs.  One was fixed in [PR #16692](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/16692) was was incorporated into matplotlib 3.3.0 (I was using 3.2.2).  [The other](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/18600) I [had to fix](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/18603) and will be in 3.4.0.  If you need this functionality now you may want to patch your `matplotlib/markers.py` to according to [this diff](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/18603/files#diff-2fc0a2b24c4797842f3b2a43f74a8273).

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, I don't know why it's designed as such. A work around is to plot a separate scatter:

```
fix, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.errorbar([1,2,3],[3,4,5], yerr=[0.5,0.5,0.5], marker=None, color='green')
plt.scatter([1,2,3],[3,4,5], s=225, marker=m, color="green")

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is the kind of thing that SHOULD be obvious to me!