# How to rotate matplotlib fill-style-markers?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

In black are matplotlib markers [that are able to rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660174/rotate-existing-matplotlib-markers/49662571#49662571) . In blue/orange are [fill-style-markers](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_fillstyle_reference.html), and I have not managed to rotate them in the same way.

Here is the code that has generated the graphics. In this version `t` is not used.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
for i in x:
    t = mpl.markers.MarkerStyle(marker='o')
    t._transform = t.get_transform().rotate_deg(-i)
    marker_style = dict(color='b',  markerfacecoloralt='orange', markeredgecolor='w', markersize=25,
                        marker='o' )    
    plt.plot(i, i, marker=(2, 0, -i), c='k',markersize=30, linestyle='None')
    plt.plot(i, i, marker=(3, 0, -i), c='k',markersize=10, linestyle='None')
    plt.plot(i, i+20,fillstyle='top', **marker_style)
plt.margins(0.15); plt.grid();plt.show()
```

I have tried without success:

```
marker_style = dict(....., marker=(3, 3, -i) ) 
or
marker_style = dict(....., marker=t ) 
or
plt.plot(i, i+20,fillstyle='top', marker=(3, 3, -i)
```

Thanks if you know and tell how to put the things together ! A solution with `plt.scatter()` would be fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it can be done using markers or MarkerStyle, the documentation only specifies how to fill the symbol divided by half. You can mimic that behavior by putting together 2 half circles and rotating them accordingly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

plt.figure(1)

x = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]

ax=plt.gca()
rot=0

for i in x:

    HalfA=mpl.patches.Wedge((i, i+20), 5,theta1=0-rot,theta2=180-rot, color='r')
    HalfB=mpl.patches.Wedge((i, i+20), 5,theta1=180-rot,theta2=360-rot, color='b')

    rot=rot+360/len(x)

    ax.add_artist(HalfA)
    ax.add_artist(HalfB)

    ax.plot(i, i, marker=(2, 0, -i), c='k',markersize=30, linestyle='None')
    ax.plot(i, i, marker=(3, 0, -i), c='k',markersize=10, linestyle='None')


ax.set_xlim((-10, 110))
ax.set_ylim((-10, 130))
```

[image: This is the output that I get]

Comment: WOW - super ! Thank you ! You can see [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245152/pyplot-plot-a-curve-with-ticks-on-one-side/54262806#54262806) what I used it for