# Vertical gradient as marker face in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to set a vertical gradient as a marker face in matplotlib? E.g. something like this:
[image: TikZ vertical gradient face]

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10958835/3714930)

Comment: [elderly related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318288/how-to-use-custom-marker-with-plot/2320099#2320099)