# Change arrow style of matplotlib quiver function

Tags: matplotlib

Is there a way to change the style of the arrows of the [matplotlib quiver function](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=quiver#matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver)?

I tried passing the `arrowprops=dict()` kwarg to the function, but that seems to only work with [annotate function](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html).

In any case the arrow style I am looking for, does not seem to be included in matplotlib. I think they are called "half arrows". I can insert these arrows using UTF-8 characters, but the arrows can then not be customized and it is hard to get them aligned properly. Is there a better way to do this (Maybe with inserting a SVG symbol)?

[image]

The code of my solution above:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mplstereonet
import matplotlib.image as image

#UTF-8 characters don't seem to work in the normal pyplot backend
plt.switch_backend("gtk3cairo")

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='stereonet')

arrows = [[120, 30, 120, 30, "sin"],
          [160, 50, 160, 50, "dex"]]

for arrow in arrows:
    strike = arrow[0] - 90
    ax.plane(strike, arrow[1], color="#000000")
    ax.line(arrow[3], arrow[2], color="#ff0000")

    x, y = mplstereonet.line(arrow[3], arrow[2])
    ang = np.degrees(np.arctan2(x, y))[0] * (-1)
    gap = 0.08
    gap_x = gap * np.sin(ang)
    gap_y = gap * np.cos(ang)

    if arrow[4] == "dex":
        ax.text(x - gap_x, y - gap_y, "⇀", size=30, rotation=ang,
                horizontalalignment="center", verticalalignment="center")
        ax.text(x + gap_x, y + gap_y, "↽", size=30, rotation=ang,
                horizontalalignment="center", verticalalignment="center")

    elif arrow[4] == "sin":
        ax.text(x - gap_x, y - gap_y, "↼", size=30, rotation=ang,
                horizontalalignment="center", verticalalignment="center")
        ax.text(x + gap_x, y + gap_y, "⇁", size=30, rotation=ang,
                horizontalalignment="center", verticalalignment="center")

plt.show()
```

Similar questions:

- [How to use custom marker with plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318288/how-to-use-custom-marker-with-plot)
- [Matplotlib custom marker/symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324270/matplotlib-custom-marker-symbol)

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This is only a partial answer, about the use of `arrowprops=dict()`.

---

> Part of the problem as that there are 7 (!) artists that can be used to draw arrows (Arrow, FancyArrow, FancyArrowPatch, ConnectionPatch, YAArrow, SimpleArrow (which is a sub-class of FancyArrowPatch) and FilledArrow) all of which behave differently and have different interfaces.
>
> This does not include quiver which does draw arrows, but is a PolyCollection sub-class.

You can read more on this arrows discussion [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3945).

Also mentioned there is that some functions change the arrow style automatically, according to the parameters given:

> [...] the issue with the annotate function is that it's not obvious to a user that the API changes when specifying a different arrowstyle.

I had a similar issue with `annotate`, which you may see [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684619/how-to-change-the-arrow-head-style-in-matplotlib-annotate).