# Plotting scatter of several polar plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset with five variables and one dependent variable. A sample of that would be:

```
v1  v2  v3  v4  s     a
1.0 0.6 0.8 0.2 56890 98.67
0.8 0.3 1.0 0.5 94948 98.00
1.0 0.8 0.1 0.3 78483 97.13
```

I want to represent visually the relation between all five variables and the dependent variable. For this purpose I was thinking of combining two types of plots:

- scatter plot between `s` and `a`
- polar plot for `v1`, `v2`, `v3` and `v4`

So essentially I want to display a small polar plot for each data point in my dataset. Something like this:

[image]

An example polar plot is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, 4, endpoint=False)
radii = [90, 90, 90, 90]
width = np.pi / 4 * np.array([1.0, 0.7, 0.6, 0.2])

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How about saving your polar plot to image first and then putting it on the final plot [as an image marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318288/how-to-use-custom-marker-with-plot)?

Comment: That could work. Is that the only alternative that anyone can think of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea can be to place a lot of small polar axes at the positions of the points. To this end, [`mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/api/inset_locator_api.html#mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes) may be used. This would be placed at coordinates `x`, `y` (`bbox_to_anchor=(x,y)`) specified in data coordinates of the main axes (`bbox_transform=axis_main.transData`). The `loc` parameter should be set to "center" (`loc=10`), such that the middle of the polar plot sits at position `(x,y)`.

You may then plot whatever you like into the polar axes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
from matplotlib.projections import get_projection_class

d = np.array([[ 1.0, 0.6, 0.8, 0.2, 56890, 98.67],
              [ 0.8, 0.3, 1.0, 0.5, 94948, 98.00],
              [ 1.0, 0.8, 0.1, 0.3, 78483, 97.13]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.margins(0.15)


def plot_inset(data, x,y, axis_main, width ):
    ax_sub= inset_axes(axis_main, width=width, height=width, loc=10, 
                       bbox_to_anchor=(x,y),
                       bbox_transform=axis_main.transData, 
                       borderpad=0.0, axes_class=get_projection_class("polar"))

    theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, 4, endpoint=False)
    radii = [90, 90, 90, 90]
    width = np.pi / 4 * data
    bars = ax_sub.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.0)
    ax_sub.set_thetagrids(theta*180/np.pi, frac=1.4)
    ax_sub.set_xticklabels(["v{}".format(i) for i in range(1,5)])
    ax_sub.set_yticks([])


for da in d:    
    plot_inset(da[:4], da[4],da[5], ax, 0.5 )

#plot invisible scatter plot for the axes to autoscale
ax.scatter(d[:,4], d[:,5], s=1, alpha=0.0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a thing of beauty. I'll try it as soon as I get home.