# Matplotlib: How to make scatter plot of arbitrary pyplot figures

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is a question linked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566284/matplotlib-how-to-plot-images-instead-of-points) well received one. In that question I see an answers on how to plot images (or different images) at different coordinates like a scatter plot.

Using [`TextArea`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/_modules/matplotlib/offsetbox.html#TextArea) I can put little strings instead of images at different coordinates.

How about if I want to put a mini version of a plot/image generated by matplotlib itself? Suppose I want instead of using an `image.jpg` I want to use the result of `plt.stem(arr)` as the image in the scatter plots.

How can I do this? How about a miniature version of the output of `plt.plot(x, y)`?

I tried modifying the function given in the linked question to be like:

```
def stem_scatter(x, y, arr, ax=None):

    from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnnotationBbox, DrawingArea

    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    im = DrawingArea(0.1, 0.1)
    im.add_artist(plt.stem(arr))
    x, y = np.atleast_1d(x, y)
    artists = []
    for x0, y0 in zip(x, y):
        ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (x0, y0), xycoords='data', frameon=False)
        artists.append(ax.add_artist(ab))
    ax.update_datalim(np.column_stack([x, y]))
    ax.autoscale()
    return artists
```

But that gives an error:
`AttributeError: 'StemContainer' object has no attribute 'is_transform_set'`

EDIT: From the linked question:

```
"…. but the second has a large advantage. The annotation box approach will allow the image to stay at a constant size as you zoom in."
```

this would be a desirable feature in an accepted answer because on zooming in one would like to see the relative positions of the scatter points. If the scatter plotted image did not maintain a fixed size (relative to the screen as opposed to current axis limits), then zooming in would be of little help.

Comment: A bit hacky, but you can use `plt.savefig` to save a picture, then use the method in the linked question

Comment: @BlackBear Indeed that (or a variation of that using PIL to avoid saving to disk) is what I am currently doing … but if you have a scatter plot with a couple of hundred points it doesn't seem like the best way.

Comment: You already got an answer by one of the matplotlib developpers. What is the bounty for? Did you try using an inset axes?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am not sure it is really an answer, rather more of a suggestion in a possible direction … which may or may not work. And ... no I didn't try, mostly because the link in the answer features a prominent warning that the feature is experimental and the API may change.

Comment: Also from the linked question: "…. but the second has a large advantage. The annotation box approach will allow the image to stay at a constant size as you zoom in.". I am not completely sure, but my experiments suggested this is not true for a naive `inset_axes` approach.

Comment: You could use `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes` instead, which is not experimental, and which offers slightly more features. See [the demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html). In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262749/plotting-scatter-of-several-polar-plots) something similar is shown. If a specific zooming / panning behaviour is required please explain it inside the question.

Comment: So did you try the inset_axes? Did you experience any problem? Is there something missing from the example that I should add?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html